# How to entirely disable linting on a specific file on vscode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Visual studio code, with the python extension, offers [code linting](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting).
While in the linked page it is documented how to generally enable/disable linting via user preferences, it is not clear if or how can I disable on a per file basis.

More specifically, I'm looking for a way to disable linting on a file, preferably via command palette or similar.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

VS-code uses Pylint to lint Python code. Pylint (versions 0.26.1 and up) can be disabled for a specific file by adding `# pylint: skip-file` to the top of the page.

See the [Pylint FAQs](https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#how-can-i-tell-pylint-to-never-check-a-given-module)

Answer (score 6):

Modify this in settings.json file:

```
"python.linting.ignorePatterns": [
    ".vscode/*.py",
    "**{filename or pattern}**",
    "**/site-packages/**/*.py"
]
```

Comment: Can this be used to ignore entire directories (including subdirectories)?